Replace subtrings in a list of strings using dictionary in python
I have a list of substrings:
ls = ['BLAH a b c A B C D 12 34 56',
    'BLAH d A B 12 45 78',
    'BLAH a/b A B C 12 45 78',
    'BLAH a/ b A  12 45 78',
    'BLAH a b c A B C D 12 34 99']

I want to replace the lower case substrings with an identifier:
dict2 = {'a b c':'1','d':'2','a/b':'3','a/ b':'4'}

I am looping over all the items in the list and trying to perform a replace using:
[[ls[i].replace(k,v) for k,v in dict2.items()][0] for i in range(len(ls))]

but this does not perform the correct replacement from the dictionary for each element(d, a/b, and a/ b were not replaced), and results in:
['BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 56', 
'BLAH d A B 12 45 78', 
'BLAH a/b A B C 12 45 78', 
'BLAH a/ b A  12 45 78', 
'BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 99']

I would like to end up with:
['BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 56',
    'BLAH 2 A B 12 45 78',
    'BLAH 3 A B C 12 45 78',
    'BLAH 4 A  12 45 78',
    'BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 99']


You need to add a tag for the language. Is this Python?

What's with the [0]? Why is that in there? Won't that replace the map with a map consisting of a single element?

This way seems to work for me.
Here is an online test: https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/2qmeh/
result = []
for s in ls:
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        s = s.replace(k, v)
    result.append(s)

print(result)


Basically @Im Kumin's answer in a comprehension:
md = list(dict2.items()) # Avoids re-computing this for each string

result = [functools.reduce(lambda s,m:s.replace(m[0],m[1]), [line]+md) for line in ls]


ls = ['BLAH a b c A B C D 12 34 56',
    'BLAH d A B 12 45 78',
    'BLAH a/b A B C 12 45 78',
    'BLAH a/ b A  12 45 78',
    'BLAH a b c A B C D 12 34 99']

dict2 = {'a b c':'1','d':'2','a/b':'3','a/ b':'4'}

original answer:
[[ls[i].replace(k,v) for k,v in dict2.items()][i] for i in range(len(ls)-1)]

#output
['BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 56',
 'BLAH 2 A B 12 45 78',
 'BLAH 3 A B C 12 45 78',
 'BLAH 4 A  12 45 78']

Edit: @Kumin's answer is correct as the last element was missing when using list comprehension:
for s in ls:
    for k, v in dict2.items():
        s = s.replace(k, v)
    print(s)

#output
BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 56
BLAH 2 A B 12 45 78
BLAH 3 A B C 12 45 78
BLAH 4 A  12 45 78
BLAH 1 A B C D 12 34 99


This answer does not provide the expected output. The last string is not converted using the Dictionary because the suggested code makes use of the coincidental fact that for the sequence of the first four strings the Dictionary entry to use is the same order as in the List
